# Unable to install SQL Server 2008 Express SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing difficulties installing the MS SQL Server Express 2008 Service Pack 1. I already have MS SQL Server Express 2008 installed and all I want to do is to install the SP1 however I get following error message even though all features are selected, it still tells me to select one or more features:
[image]

Also just for information, when I open the SQL Server Configuration Manager to manage my SQL Server Services, the following error message is displayed:
[image]

If anyone who has faced this and has a solution then please let me know, as my aim is to install management studio, but for that I must have SP1 installed at least, and I'm stuck at that point.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
please follow : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx

and your solution is :
1) Installation type is perform new installation sql 2008 from option and con't
```

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. I chose the wrong option for installation.